# Django Query in a loop fails for no good reason

Tags: django, object, loops

I have this code:

```
msgs = int(post['time_in_weeks'])
for i in range(msgs):
    tip_msg = Tip.objects.get(week_number=i)
```

it always results in an error saying that no values could be found.

week_number is an integer field. When I input the value of i directly,
the query works.

When i print out the value of i I get the expected values.

Any input at all would be seriously appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work either:

tip_msg = Tip.objects.filter(category=2).order_by("week_number")[i]

Its as if Django treats i as a non integer even when i use int(i) this still fails.

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function will give you a zero based list of numbers up to and excluding `msgs`. I guess there is no Tip with `week_number=0`.

Comment: There is a Tip with week_number=0.

Comment: Even when I use i+1 instead of i still have the same problem. Ultimately trying to get just a distinct value for tip_msg. This all runs on GAE via django non_rel: http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel/wiki/Home All other queries still work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to limit the number of queries you could do this:

```
for tip in Tip.objects.filter(week_number__lt=msgs):
    #do something
```

or, if you want specific weeks:

```
weeks=(1,3,5)
for tip in Tip.objects.filter(week_number__in=weeks):
    #do something
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Its a much better way I hadn't even thought of.